# Bootstrap 4 Buttonwith iFont icon pushes text outside

Tags: button, text, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a download button with an icon on it, using Bootstrap 4 and Font awsome for the icon.
The thing is when I add the icon using:

```
<i class="fa fa-mobile fa-3x pull-left" ></i>
```

it pushes the text out of the button, and I can't get the button width to grow with the contents.

Here is my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/48/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are floating your `<i>` element.

Remove the `pull-left` class from `<i>` and try this:

```
<a class="d-inline-flex flex-nowrap">
</a>
```

And add a margin class to your `txtAppStore` `div`. For example:

```
<div id="txtAppStore" class="ml-3"></div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/50/

Comment: Note that in your fiddle it won't work because you are targeting Bootstrap Alpha 2, try targeting the latest: [Alpha 6](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that i had the following CSS, that I missed, and was limiting my button size:

```
.black-background {
background-color:#000000;
padding: 6px;
width:150px;
}
```

I've comment that out, and did some changes accoding to the first answer, and now it looks goot, Thank you!
http://jsfiddle.net/dumitrudan608/x1hphsvb/52/

Comment: You are referencing my fiddle solution, but I don't think that was your intention

Comment: Yes, sorry update that QuantumHive, i sent the wrong jsfiddle. But you did offer me most of my solution, Thank you for that. I updated my previous comment. I am 1 reputation point away from being able to upvote your answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure that your answer answers your question? You are saying that you were limiting your button size because of the `width:150px;`, but in your question you included a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/48/). In this fiddle there is **no** such thing as a `width`. Like I said before, the *problem* is because you used `pull-left`. If you remove the `pull-left` class from your original fiddle, you will see that the button fill wrap it's contents.

Answer (score -1):

just define width for #txtAppStore, or put that all to Bootstrap div like col-md-3 and center it, then inside col-md-3 you can putt this button with width: 100%; and for example inside txt for 80% of width. 
Quickest solutions but not "auto" is:

```
#txtAppStore {
  width: 150px;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a flexible solution

Comment: I told what to do if need % bootstrap,